# Postgres : ShareLock Deadlock on transaction

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

Recently we have started getting lot of deadlock errors in logs. (Postgres server 9.6.5)

Our table consist of two columns one is an auto-increment primary key , while other is a json object.
two attributes from json object are defined as unique .
Now in logs we keep on getting errors that two simple insert queries on different rows are blocking each other.

============

```
process 65325 detected deadlock while waiting for ShareLock on transaction 2934224126 after 1000.050 ms

DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 35530. Wait queue: .

CONTEXT:  while inserting index tuple (128,10) in relation "A"

STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO A AS t (info) VALUES('{"x":"y",....)

ERROR:  deadlock detected

DETAIL:  Process 65325 waits for ShareLock on transaction 2934224126; blocked by process 35530.

Process 35530 waits for ShareLock on transaction 2934224125; blocked by process 65325.

Process 65325: INSERT INTO A AS t (info) VALUES({"x":"y",....)

Process 35530: INSERT INTO A AS t (info) VALUES({"x":"z",....)
```

====================

So basically two different rows are in deadlock condition.
Is there any suggestion on what conditions such deadlocks may occur?

Comment: There were several bugfixes related to "spurious deadlock" between your outdated version 9.6.5 and the current version 9.6.16. https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.6.5&to=9.6.16&keywords=

Answer (score 10):

Rows can never be in deadlock.  It is not two different rows, but two different transactions, that are in deadlock.  Your log is showing you the *most recent* insertion attempt by each transaction.  Presumably, there were previous inserts as well in each transaction.  But those won't show up in the log, unless they show up for some other reason (like log_statement=all).

So if T1 successfully (and invisibly, looking at your log file) inserted "x":"y", the T2 successfully and invisibly inserted "x":"z", and now T1 tries to insert "x":"z" and T2 tries "x":"y", there will be a deadlock.  Assuming the unique index is on info->>'x'

This would be the same issue if you were not using JSON.

Mitigations would be, don't insert more than one row per transaction.  Or if you do, always insert them in a specified order (for example, "y" before "z" due to the latin alphabet ordering), although in this case you just replace the deadlock error with a unique key violation.  Or, just be prepared to catch the deadlock and try again.

Comment: Thanks , Although logging seems confusing because of explicit mention of queries which are not conflicting the unique constraints.I will try to implement your mitigation suggestions.

Comment: @varun The statements mentioned in the log are part of the conflict, they just aren't the entirety of it.  PostgreSQL doesn't keep a memory of what statements had executed previously in the current transaction, so it can't report them.  (Perhaps it should be taught to keep a limited-sized buffer with historical statements)

Comment: Yes , if we have historical statements also ,deadlock understanding will become obvious.Thanks again!

Comment: Upvoted as this hint helped fix a deadlock issue I was getting where multiple servers were writing data to the same table even though each set of rows would be unique by server. Simply ordering the rows fixed the issue. Thanks @jjanes